# Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x1079d85d8) to 'App.DetailViewController'

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

i am trying to view a tab bar controller on my master detail controller,this is the code which seems to project an error with the threads. Thanks!

```
  let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
```

Comment: It simply means that what you get as a topViewcontroller is a UITabBarController

Comment: Please post all the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this issues produce In that case you Contact the NavigationController in DetailViewController after the You Push the NavigationController of DetailViewController **'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'** 
Your ViewController hierarchy wrong in TabBarView Application 
 [image]
 1. any Controller Connected which have as First ViewController with UITabbarController (RootViewController  **EmbedIn**  UINavigationController) after the DetailViewController Connect With Button Segue or push to Button's Action then App Properly working
[image]
 2. List item

But When you Present Detail View Controller then no have any crashes received. app properly work
[image]